# How to make embeds through dm's Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm working on a bot in discord.py rewrite and am trying to make a command to make embeds through dm's. The problem is the bot does not await the messages. here is my code Thanks!

```
@client.command()
async def c_embed(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  perms = ctx.author.permissions_in(ctx.channel)
  if perms.administrator:
    em = discord.Embed(description='What would you like the title to be?', color = discord.Colour.red())
    await user.send(embed=em)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message')
    title = msg.content
    em = discord.Embed(description='What would you like the Description to be?', color = discord.Colour.red())
    await user.send(embed=em)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message')
    desc = msg.content
    em = discord.Embed(title = "**Confirm Channel**", description = "Choose a channel for this msg to be in. Put Channel ID")
    em = discord.Embed(title=title, description=desc,color=discord.Colour.red())
    channel = msg.content
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=em)
    return
```

Comment: And what's the issue here? You just put a bunch of code and what are we supposed to do with it? Any errors/tracebacks? What's the result? What's the expected result. Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: After testing your code I do not see any errors. Please explain in more detail, as Łukasz Kwieciński  mentioned, what is wrong.

Comment: there are no errors when I run it. But when I use the command it does not await the users message.

Comment: Maybe the user does not allow DMs

Comment: No, im testing the command on myself and I havee my dm's on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved now due to lots of reading the docs and testing
instead of just waiting for a response the bot awaits for the users response.

by using:

```
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check = lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
```

it only takes the response from the author which makes it wait in dm's.

```
@client.command()
async def c_embed(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  perms = ctx.author.permissions_in(ctx.channel)
  if perms.administrator:
    em = discord.Embed(description='What would you like the title to be?', color = discord.Colour.red())
    await user.send(embed=em)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    title = msg.content
    em = discord.Embed(description='What would you like the Description to be?', color = discord.Colour.red())
    await user.send(embed=em)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    desc = msg.content
    em = discord.Embed(title = "**Confirm Channel**", description = "Choose a channel for this msg to be in. Put Channel ID", color = discord.Colour.red())
    await user.send(embed=em)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    channel = msg.content
    em = discord.Embed(title=title, description=desc,color=discord.Colour.red())
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=em)
    return
```